# Beamer overlays and counters: compiling loop

Tags: beamer, counters

I tried to compile

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\newcounter{xxslide}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \addtocounter{xxslide}{2} 
  \visible<\value{xxslide}>{blabla}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

But the compiler generated an infinite amount of slides. How can I control number of overlays while programming a slide?

The point is that I'm making a complicated drawing. During the presentation things need to appear and disappear. I want to make macro's that say: show blabla during 5 overlays of a slide. Now, we go to the next overlay. Show blabla for the next 3 overlays and so on ... When I switch to the next overlay, I want to increment a counter that expresses the number of the current overlay and then use \visible < xxslide, xxslide+5 > { blabla } commands.

Comment: The frame contents are compiled at each slide for overlay effects. So `\addtocounter` continuously adds 2 at each slide. Take the `\addtocounter` command out of the frame and it works.

Comment: How do you "go to the next overlay"? Do you use a `\pause`, or how do you determine what the next overlay is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not quite sure how your drawing is structured at the moment, but from what I understand, you could use the `\pause` command in combination with the `.` (dot) overlay specification to achieve what you want:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

Overlay number: \insertpagenumber

\visible<-.(3)>{This text is shown 3 overlays long, starting from overlay 1}\pause

\visible<-.(5)>{This text is shown 5 overlays long, starting from overlay 2}\pause

\visible<-.(2)>{This text is shown 2 overlays long, starting from overlay 3}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: resulting output, showing six overlays]

<sub>*(Click on the image to see it full-size.)*</sub>

It works like this: Each time a `\pause` command is encountered, the counter `beamerpauses` is increased by one, starting from 1. The dot in an overlay specification returns the value of this counter *minus one*, without changing the counter itself. If followed by an optional offset in round brackets, it returns `(beamerpauses - 1) + offset` instead, again without affecting the counter itself.

Take for example the second `\visible` command in the above example: As it is preceded by one `\pause`, it is shown from the second overlay on. The dot in the overlay specification returns `(2 - 1) + 5 = 6`, so the text is shown until overlay number 6.

Like this, you can specify how long a certain element of your drawing should be visible in the overlay specification, while managing the order of their appearance using `\pause` commands.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution based on the `pgffor` package (not sure of having get the point).

Code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\foreach \xxslide in {1,3}{
\visible<\xxslide->{Text}
}
\newline
\visible<2>{Hello}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Now you can control the overlays by inserting them as list.

Comment: The point is that I'm making a complicated drawing. During the presentation things need to appear and disappear. I want to make macro's that say: show blabla during 5 overlays of a slide. Now, we go to the next overlay. Show blabla for the next 3 overlays and so on ... When I switch to the next overlay, I want to increment a counter that expresses the current overlay. When I switch to the next overlay, I want to increment a counter that expresses the current overlay and then use \visible < xxslide, xxslide+5 > { blabla } commands.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Diabonas, a simple representation of my problem is to make a moving snake. The code is below:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\headsnake}[1]{
  \visible<.-.(3)>{\draw (#1) ellipse (0.5 and 0.5); \pause}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{A moving snake}
  \begin{figure}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
     \headsnake{0,0}
     \headsnake{0,1}
     \headsnake{1,1}
     \headsnake{2,1}
     \headsnake{2,2}
     \headsnake{2,3}
     \headsnake{2,4}
     \headsnake{2,5}
     \headsnake{3,5}
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{figure}
 \end{frame}

 \end{document}
```

[image: result moving snake]